# PyroCMS Language Tag to display the language code

Tags: pyrocms, pyrocms-lex

I'm using PyroCMS Pro 2.2.6. I created in a PyorCMS Stream a language field which I would like to use in my template to display the language code (en, de, fr, etc.):
[image: PyroCMS Language Field]

I tried many different tags like:

```
{{ web_language }}
{{ web_language:name }}
{{ web_language:value }}
{{ web_language:key }}
{{ web_language:code }}
```

Only the first one worked and displayed the language value (English, Germany, etc.). Which tag can I use to display the language code?

BTW there seems to be missing the label above the radio buttons when you choose *PyroCMS Language* as field type.

Comment: That's not possible with this field type. It only displays the actual name of the language, not the code. The "Yes/No" option means "Should we filter by the current theme and what languages they support?" - straight out of the source code in system/cms/modules/streams_core/field_types/pyro_lang/field.pyro_lang.php. Soooo - depending on what you're trying to do, you'll have to look for another way.

Comment: Thanks! The question is then how I can show the right language code in the html tag? <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

Comment: You can use the constant CURRENT_LANGUAGE (http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/developers/tools/constants-and-globals) or the language plugin `{{ lang:code }}`. The latter gives you the language of the currenty logged in user, or the system default if no user is logged in.